# why i can not find any symbols in libs/armeabi/libtest.so

Tags: android, android-ndk, nm

When I use `ndk`, I can not find symbols in `shared_libraries`.

Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

test.cpp:

```
void fun() {}
```

after ndk-build, nm /libs/armeabi/libtest.so, the result is no symbols, why ?

Answer (score 0):

@auselen is right about `NDK_DEBUG=1`, but also bear in mind that you have to use the right `nm`: if you use the default `nm` from your computer, which is most probably an x86 computer, it won't be able to read the symbols of a library compiled for an ARM architecture (most android phones).

The right `nm` to use for your output lib located in `libs/armeabi/` is:
`${you_ndk_folder}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-*/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin`

(The `darwin-x86_64` is if you're developping on Mac, it's different if you're on Windows or Linux, but you get the idea..)

Comment: I don't this is true, regular `nm` should just work since it is an elf utility.